# Entity framework code first generates DB column for property that does not exist on the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity framework 5.0 code first. My model class looks like this:

```
    public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
    }

    public int ClientID { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public MeritalStatus MeritalStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Salutation { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

I use DropCreateDatabase initializer in global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer<SiteObjectContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SiteObjectContext>());
```

So DB is recreated each time model changes.

The database table that is generated looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
[ClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerNumber] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[MeritalStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
[BirthDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Gender] [int] NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Salutation] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Visa_VisaID] [int] NULL)
```

It somehow produces redundant column Visa_VisaID that
does not exist on the model. I suspect it can be sort of a cache as it's possible that
I had this column on the table before.
Tried dropping database manually, using EF 6 RC instead of 5.0, nothing helps, the column
reappears on each database recreation.

Visa entity:

```
    public class Visa
{
    public Visa()
    {
    }

    public int VisaID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ApplicationId { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public virtual VisaApplication Application { get; set; }
    public int MainApplicantId { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("MainApplicantId")]
    public virtual Client MainApplicant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Client> IncludedCustomers { get; set; }
    public int VisaTypeId { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("VisaTypeId")]
    public virtual VisaType VisaType { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsMultiple { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ExpiryDateStay { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDateTravel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime FirstEntryBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your Client class linked to another class called Visa?

Comment: Added Visa class to the above

Comment: And there is a relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Visa_VisaID column is created because of the Visa.IncludedCustomers property. 
The Visa_VisaID field is the FK to visa for the one-to-many relationship Visa-Clients. It is created because the association is not seen as the bi-directional.
If your case is a many to many relationship, then you should override the OnModelCreating of the DbContext to change the mapping between Client and Visa:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Visa>().HasMany(v => v.IncludedCustomers).WithMany();
}
```

This will create a table VisaIncludedCustomers table with the two Id columns as foreign keys(to Visa and Client).